# How can initialize a function mobile only?

Tags: magento2, jquery, html, mobile

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div id="element">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div data-role="collapsible">
          <div data-role="trigger">
              <span>Title 1</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div data-role="collapsible">
          <div data-role="trigger">
              <span>Title 2</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div data-role="collapsible">
          <div data-role="trigger">
              <span>Title 4</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">Content 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
require(['jquery','accordion'], function ($) {
        $("#element").accordion({
             "openedState": "active",
            "collapsible": true,
            "active": [0,1,2,3], /** Integrat Dynamic open tab  */
            "multipleCollapsible": true,
        });
    });
```

I have a function called an accordion and I want it's initialization to be only on the mobile (do not call on the desktop).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The [recommended](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_js.html) way would be to use `matchMedia`.

```
require(['jquery','accordion', 'matchMedia' ], function ($, mediaCheck) {

            mediaCheck({
                media: '(min-width: 768px)',
                // Switch to Desktop Version
                entry: function () {},
                // Switch to Mobile Version
                exit: function () {
                    $("#element").accordion({
                    "openedState": "active",
                    "collapsible": true,
                    "active": [0,1,2,3], /** Integrat Dynamic open tab  */
                    "multipleCollapsible": true,
                })
            }
    })
})
```

Comment: Even after using media check i can not get to switch jquery activate/deactivate on window resize.

Comment: You can use: $("#element").accordion("deactivate"); function in in entry function. More info can be found: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html

Comment: Can you tell me how to disable and keep open at the same time? I have tried this but when disabling, it first hides it and then disables.

 mediaCheck({
     media: '(max-width: 767px)',
     entry: function() {
      $('.collapsible-init').collapsible({})
     },
     exit: function() {
      if($('.collapsible-init').data('collapsible')) {
       $(".collapsible-init").collapsible("activate");
       $('.collapsible-init').collapsible('disable');
      }
     }       
    });

Comment: TLDR. One needs to use the css

Answer (score 1):

Less then 640 width would be mobile you can check this below way

```
require(['jquery','accordion'], function ($) {
    if ($(window).width() < 640) {
           $("#element").accordion({
             "openedState": "active",
             "collapsible": true,
             "active": [0,1,2,3], /** Integrat Dynamic open tab  */
             "multipleCollapsible": true,
         });
     }
 });
```